# How to write a regex for words like [[gold]] or [[Archimedes]]

Tags: java, regex, string

I have an  array of strings. I am checking for the following pattern in each element of the array: `[[some word]]`.

The element should start with two square brackets and end with 2 square brackets with a word or a sentence in between them.

I also need to extract the string "some word" from `[[some word]]`. I am unable to figure out the regular expressions in Java. They appear to be very different from scripting language like PHP.

Eg. If I encounter `[[this is an example]]` while traversing the array, I should output `"this is an example"`. This should be done for all strings enclosed in double square brackets.

Comment: Take a look at `java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(String s)` which will return a valid regular expression for a string literal. E.g. `"hello [[sir]]!".matches(Pattern.quote("[[sir]]"))`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code and the problem you are facing

Comment: It’s the same regular expression as in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code:

```
String input = "How to write a regex for words like [[gold]] or [[Archimedes]] in JAVA";
String regex = "\\[\\[(.*?)\\]\\]";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
int idx=0;
while(matcher.find(idx)){
  String match = matcher.group(1);
  System.out.println(match);
  idx = matcher.end();
}
```

prints:

```
gold
Archimedes
```

The actual regex (without escaped `\`) is:

```
\[\[(.*?)\]\]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 2):

I believe this regex should work for you:

```
"(?s)\\[\\[(.*?)\\]\\]"
```

This will also grab multi line sentence between `[[` and `]]` because of use of `(?s)` (DOTALL)

Comment: haha. I dont understand it , looks like a bunch of lines.

If you dont mind , can you explain me briefly @anubhava

Comment: Sure: `\\[\\[` means match 2 left square brackets. `\\]\\]` means match 2 right square brackets. `.*?` means 0 or more character between 2 square brackets. `?` is for making it non-greedy. I already wrote what `(?s)` means. Here is the very helpful site on regex: regular-expressions.info

Answer (score 0):

`\\[\\[([^]]*)\\]\\]` can be used as a slight variation on @anubhava's answer. As the comments here point out, it won't catch `[[a]b]]`, but I couldn't tell whether that was part of your requirement or not.

Comment: It's not greedy because of the `?` in `.*?`

Comment: Your regex will not catch `[[ab]cd]]`

Comment: @rzymek - hmm, you're right; my mistake. I'm not used to using the backoff operators like that; I always go straight for negation.

Comment: @Space Pope: I usually do too. Though `.*?` looks better than `[^]]*`, especially in this case (`]`)